# weird missing header on mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I'm new to mac so please hang on with me. I have to compile a homemade package which compiles and runs in linux, and uses the boost libraries. First I was getting all kind of estrange errors from the compiler, until I realized that I was using gcc 4.2. I installed 4.8. I tried with clang but for some reason (which I do not understand) the version that got installed was 2.1:

```
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 2.1 (tags/Apple/clang-163.7.1) (based on LLVM 3.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

I'm using OS X 10.9.4, Kernel Version: Darwin 13.3.0.

I installed boost using macports. When I tried to compile, the compiler couldn't find the headers so I did:

```
     export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/include/
```

and the compiler found them. Now, when I run the makefile, I get:

```
In file included from /opt/local/lib/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/4.8.2/include/stdint.h:9:0,
                 from /opt/local/include/gcc48/c++/cstdint:41,
                 from /opt/local/include/gcc48/c++/bits/char_traits.h:376,
                 from /opt/local/include/gcc48/c++/ios:40,
                 from /opt/local/include/gcc48/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /opt/local/include/gcc48/c++/iostream:39,
                 from ../src/space/space.h:4,
                 from ../src/space/grid_space.cpp:1:
/opt/local/lib/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/4.8.2/include-fixed/stdint.h:27:32: fatal error: sys/_types/_int8_t.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/_types/_int8_t.h>
                                ^
compilation terminated.
```

and I cannot find where sys/_types/_int8_t.h is or how to install it if missing. I've read around to do xcode-select -install, but what I get is:

```
xcode-select -install
Usage: xcode-select -print-path
   or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>
   or: xcode-select -version
Arguments:
   -print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
   -switch <xcode_folder_path>     Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
   -version                        Prints xcode-select version information
```

while

```
xcodebuild -version
Xcode 5.1.1
Build version 5B1008
```

what's going on? where can I find sys/_types/_int8_t.h ?

I would like to use clang, but the version is too old and I need C++11 support. Clang is installed correctly, where it should be, and:

```
 $ xcode-select -p
Usage: xcode-select -print-path
   or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>
   or: xcode-select -version
Arguments:
   -print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
   -switch <xcode_folder_path>     Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
   -version                        Prints xcode-select version information
```

Comment: You're trying to compile linux headers with an OS X version of GCC — it's a recipe for disaster. If you're trying to use boost then start with [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html).

Comment: I compiled them, and got the same error. I tried to compile a hello world program and couldn't. I'm putting the extra info right now.

Comment: Use `clang++` to compile and link C++ programs.

Comment: I think using `gcc` is a mistake and clang should be able to cope.  If you've installed `boost` via MacPorts then you must have `clang` correctly installed as it will use `clang` to build any packages.  I would revert the installation of `gcc` and find out what that `clang` is you are picking up (use `where clang`; it should be `/usr/bin/clang`).  Also you should have `xcode-select` set-up correctly (post the output of `xcode-select -p`) but MacPorts wouldn't have worked if that wasn't set-up.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but I need C++11 and the version of clang installed doesn't support anything.... I'm putting more info on the question.

Comment: Run `xcode-select -switch /Application/Xcode.app`.  Then see what `clang --version` says.

Comment: I still get 2.1. If could update it I'd be happy

Comment: Setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (an environment variable indicating where to look for dynamic library files) to `/opt/local/include` (a folder for headers) is not going to fix anything.

Comment: "I'm new to mac", but your mac installation is new too, or you inherited the computer from someone else?

Comment: I set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH because the compiler couldn't find the boost headers, and it did fix it. The machine is not mine, is a server to which I was given access. So, I have no idea if the installation is new. What seems crazy is that I get clang 2.1.